# Intermittent Oledb connection error "Cannot open database ''."

Tags: .net, winforms, ms-access, oledb, connection-string

We are occasionally seeing this error:

> Cannot open database ''.  It may not
>   be a database that your application
>   recognizes, or the file may be
>   corrupt.

This is a Winforms .NET 2.0 product on a Jet/Access DB using Oledb connections.

This error occurs only intermittently. Make the same request a couple of minutes before/after and everything is OK. So we know that in principle the connectionstring etc is fine and the database is up and running and healthy.

Might this be a connection pooling issue? If so, how can we check/confirm this? And what are the steps to resolve. I seem to remember with the Sql connectors in .Net you have some control over the connection pooling whereas with OleDB the connection pooling is 
built in.