# ASEOLEDB client connection fails intermittently

Tags: .net, connection-string, oledb, sap-ase

I have a C++ .NET 2003 client application using Sybase 15 that is connecting to a Sybase 12.5 database server using ASEOLEDB. The client code builds the connection string and executes a stored procedure by calling [the Microsoft library function CCommand::Open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d44k0xyy(v=vs.71).aspx).

Most of the time, CCommand::Open returns S_OK and the code continues. However, seemingly randomly, that call will begin to return E_FAIL. The database, stored procedure, and input are all the same. This will last for 20-30 minutes, then seemingly resolve itself and start working again.

When the issue occurs, I can use Toad for Sybase to execute the stored procedure with the same input without issue. I can also use an older build of the client application that uses Sybase 11 that also has no issue. I can also run a script in PowerShell with the same Sybase 15 connection string that also executes successfully.

I suspect some sort of connection pooling difference between the Sybase 11 and Sybase 15 client code to be the issue, but I don't know how to prove it/disprove it/isolate the cause further.

Possible related question: [Intermittent Oledb connection error “Cannot open database ''.”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542988/intermittent-oledb-connection-error-cannot-open-database)

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue was with the Sybase OLE DB driver we were using (sybdrvoledb.dll version 15.0.0.356). When I would replace the Sybase/DataAccess/OLEDB/dll folder with the dll folder from a Sybase 15.7 version the issue would not occur. I used DLL files from Sybase 15.7.0.80 and 15.7.0.1000 and both would fix the issue.